# A Copy Constructor Error during testing with list STL

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

The following codes occur a runtime error which might be very easy.
Would you Correct it?

The code is for testing STL library with list.

The problem looks that it stems from the two functions which are Test::Test(const Test& t)
 and Test& Test::operator= (const Test& m).

I want to just run it without error.

If you exactly know why the problem occurs, let me know the reason.

// header

```
class Test
{
public:
    int t;
    char *name;

public:
    Test() {
        t = 1;
        name = new char [strlen("test")+1];
        strcpy(name, "ssss");
    }
    Test (int i) {
        t = i;
    }

    Test(const Test& t);              
    ~Test()
    { 
        delete [] name;
    }
    Test& operator= (const Test& m);

    char * get_name();
};
```

// implementation

```
Test::Test(const Test& t)
{
    this->t = t.t;
    this->name = new char[strlen(t.name)+1];
    strcpy(this->name, t.name);
}

Test& Test::operator= (const Test& m)
{
    if(this == &m) return *this;

    if(this->name != NULL) delete[] name;

    name = new char[strlen(m.name)+1];
    strcpy(this->name, m.name);

    this->t = m.t;

    return *this;
}

char * Test::get_name()
{
    return name;
}
```

// main function

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    Test a;
    Test b(3);
    Test c(4);

    list <Test> t_list;
    t_list.push_back(a);
    t_list.push_back(b);
    t_list.push_back(c);

    list <Test>::iterator iter_begin = t_list.begin();
    list <Test>::iterator iter_end = t_list.end();

    for(; iter_begin != iter_end; iter_begin++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", iter_begin->t);
        printf("%s\n", iter_begin->get_name());
    }

    list <Test> t_list2;
    t_list2.push_back(c);
    t_list2.push_back(b);
    t_list2.push_back(a);

    iter_begin = t_list2.begin();
    iter_end = t_list2.end();

    for(; iter_begin != iter_end; iter_begin++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", iter_begin->t);
        printf("%s\n", iter_begin->get_name());
    }



}
```

Comment: The correction would be to use `std::string`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Test(int)` constructor does not initialize `name`. This causes all the other problems. (A quick run of `valgrind` would have told you that.)